# Is it necessary to use wait , notify and notifyAll methods to synchronize threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

When we actually need to use the wait, `notify` and `notifyAll` methods, isn't the `synchronized` keyword is enough to `synchronize threads`.

Comment: That depends on how you define "synchronize threads". If it is just to prevent concurrent access to some piece of code then `synchronized` is probably sufficient, if the threads need to interoperate (e.g. producer-consumer) it might not (the consumer might want to wait until it gets notified of new messages/elements/whatever by the procuder).

Comment: You mainly need those when you wish your threads to **communicate** with each other; like some waiting until another one is done ... and those methods allow you to handle that in an efficient way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, IMO the question to which you linked is a very weak example of how wait() and notify() should be used.  See the Oracle 'guarded blocks' tutorial.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @jameslarge Let's find a better one.

Comment: @KiranKumar, you can see the true purpose of wait()/notify() if you read the tutorial that I linked to in my previous comment.  In a nutshell:  You use wait() and notify() whenever you need one or more threads to wait until some other thread makes some condition become true (e.g., to wait until a queue becomes not-empty).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I tried.  I couldn't find any that come right to the point, but the new "Documentation" project had nothing to say about wait()/notify() either, so I started a new topic there  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/5409/wait-notify#t=201608111547289865395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Why use Synchronization?

The synchronization is mainly used-

```
To prevent thread interference.
To prevent consistency problem.
```

What are the types of Synchronization?

There are two types of synchronization

```
Process Synchronization
Thread Synchronization
```

In case of Thread Synchronization

There are two types of thread synchronization mutual exclusive and inter-thread communication.

```
Mutual Exclusive
    Synchronized method.
    Synchronized block.
    static synchronization.
Cooperation (Inter-thread communication in java)
```

If you understand all these, its the answer to your question.

It depends on how and in what purpose you are using `Synchronization`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I got the answer what I want, I knew it, but some how I couldn't think of those scenario. Thank you.